# Unable to receive messages from the server using pysockets

Tags: python, sockets

I have been trying to create a simple socket program. I have been following this [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html)

```
This is my code:
def send(message):
    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = 123
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.accept((HOST, PORT))
        text = message.encode('utf-8')
        s.sendall(bytes(text))
        

    print("printing from send func", repr(text))


def receive():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.accept(("localhost", 1234))

    while True:
        msg = s.recv(1024)
        dmsg = msg.decode('utf-8')
        if len(dmsg) > 60:
            print(dmsg)
            return dmsg
```

I have a server.py code and my server is up and running. I should receive a hello world message every time I send something to the server but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `s.accept` lines to `s.connect`. Both of the functions serves as client functions.